# Can an ethernet shield function as an adapter?

Tags: serial, usb, ethernet-shield

I want to communicate with my Arduino over a long distance so I decided to use an Ethernet cable between my computer and Arduino. Searching up a few tutorials I've found them all mentioning IP addresses and establishing a network.

Simply put my question is can an Ethernet shield make the Arduino function basically the same as with a direct USB connection into its port(with Serial and all) without having to establish a network/other things. If so, is it as simple as saying something like "Ethernet.begin()" and then continuing?

Thank you, and please note that I (clearly) do not have much TCP/IP experience (but am more than willing to learn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. Ethernet is *very* different from a serial link.
You will have to deal with IP addresses, port numbers, the notions of
client and server, and so on. Note that, once you manage to establish a
TCP connection through Ethernet, *that connection* does behave pretty
much like a (somewhat virtualized) serial link. But you have to
establish the connection first. So you will have to study a bit, read
documentations, etc.

Alternatively, if you only need a short-distance link (say, a couple of
km), you can try RS-485 instead of Ethernet. RS-485 is a physical layer
commonly used to transmit regular serial data. From the software point
of view, it is pretty much a regular serial link, save for the fact that
you usually cannot speak and listen at the same time (you could, with
more expensive cabling).

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very illuminating. A quick question, to establish the TCP connection between computer and Arduino would I need any components other than the Arduino, Ethernet shield, and my computer?

Comment: @iceninja21: You well need a network cable. All the rest is software.

Comment: can't you use a crossover cable and a manual IP to connect 2 devices w/o a network?

Comment: @dandavis: If you use IP, you are doing networking, even with only two devices.